# Why would guides in Adobe Illustrator not move?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides, document-setup

I have guides in Adobe Illustrator that I can't move. They look like this:

[image]

I can't even select them. Any ideas why would that be? How do I move them?

Guides are not locked:

[image]

Comment: Is this document specific, or does it work if you create a new document with guides?  Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem. Also what version of Illustrator are you using? If you suspect a bug, probably better to post on the Adobe forum (although they never seem to fix anything).

Comment: Probably not a bug, I think this is a clear case of guides locked at layer level.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you have there, but if they're sitting on a locked layer, they could be locked by the layer itself. Check your layers using <kbd>F7</kbd> and see if any of these guides are placed on locked layer.

If guide options show unlocked, you're probably looking at another layer. A locked layer will lock any guides placed on that specific layer.

Not being able to select these guides is another indication they are probably trapped inside a locked layer.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see how the document is constructed, and assuming that it's not just a general bug, my guess is that either:

a) *The guides are on a locked layer*, or

b) *The guides are "object" locked and not "guide" locked*